# Does Apache POI no longer maintain 4.x version?

Tags: apache-poi

A program created using version 4 of [Apache POI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI) was rejected by security certification. This is because it is not the latest version (5.x).

Does Apache POI no longer maintain version 4?

Comment: [apparently not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI)

Comment: @OlafKock ohh... ok. thanks.

Comment: You might find a company that will provide paid-for support, but the community who look after Apache POI as volunteers at no charge only look after the latest version

Comment: What kind of security certification? E.g., internal or external?

Comment: Adding to Peters question why would an update to 4.x be regarded safe vs. a new major version? FYI: Every now and then, we have a discussion if we increase major or minor version based on the included changes. I'm curious on how security certification companies "tick" ...